# Rspec format Post parameters to String values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec2

When I send an object json all fields inside are changed to string, breaking my validation in the controller and i get the following error.

```
Api::V1::BillsController POST #create when logged in 
     Failure/Error: post :create, { bill: bill_attributes }
     Apipie::ParamInvalid:
       Invalid parameter 'value' value "41.64794235693306": Must be Float
     # ./app/controllers/concerns/exception_aspects.rb:4:in exception_wrapper
     # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/bills_controller_spec.rb:135:in block (4 levels) in <top (required)>
```

My test I try indicate `request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'`

```
let(:bill_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for :bill }

before(:each) do
   request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
   post :create, { bill: bill_attributes }
end

it "when is valid description" do
    expect(json_response[:description]).to eq(bill_attributes[:description])
end
```

My factory is

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :bill do
  description { FFaker::Lorem.phrase }
  value { (rand() * 100).to_f }
 end
end
```

My controller validations are

```
api :POST, "/bills", "Add a new bill to an event"
description "Add a new bill"
param :bill, Hash, :required => true, :action_aware => true do
    param :description, String, "Bill description"
    param :bill_photo, Hash, :required => false do
        param :base64image, String, "Base 64 image file"
    end
    param :value, Float, "Amount of the bill"
end
```

I try to change validation :value from `Float` to `:number` but the problem continues

I am using `rails 4.2.3` and `rspec 3.3.0`

Comment: I thought all parameters were submitted as strings.  How will a float be submitted to the api?

Comment: @Swards I try to send an object json  `{ bill: { description: 'this is description', value:52.54  }  }`

Comment: If you look at the params hash in the controller, all the params will be strings.  You can test if the format of the string would be a valid float

Comment: If your json-consumer is expecting a non-string value, the controller-action will fail, and testing is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added format json to post request and It worked like charm

```
before(:each) do
   post :create, { bill: bill_attributes, format: :json }
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. RajeshT has the right answer.

Answer (score 22):

```
post :create, params: {}, as: :json
```

This is what works in Rails 5.0.3 and rspec-rails 3.6.0

Rails controller specs now inherit from ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest instead of ActionController::TestCase. But RSpec controller specs still use ActionController::TestCase which is deprecated.
[Relevant Rails commit here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26212)

Comment: But "as: :json"  with "post" converts my integers to strings.

Answer (score 1):

None of above works for me.(rails 5.1.7, rspec 3.6)
The simple way you can give it a try is stub ActionController::Parameters 
In my case, in controller I always use permit for strong parameters.

```
def product_parameters
  _params = params.permit :name, :price

  # validate for price is integer
  raise BadRequest, code: 'blah_code' unless _params[:price].is_a?(Integer)
end
```

and then in Rspec I stub ActionController::Parameters like below

```
allow_any_instance_of(ActionController::Parameters).to receive(:permit).and_return(ActionController::Parameters.new(name: 'product name', price: 3000).permit(:name, :price)
```

just like that, and Rspec test checking Integer will work

> NOTE: This can also apply with send boolean, float in params too.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 4 We can try this

```
post 'orders.json', JSON.dump(order: {boolean: true, integer: 123}), "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case using rails 4.2, rspec 3.5 and ruby 2.3

```
post '/api/webhooks/v1/subscriptions', { abc: 134 }.to_json, headers
```

the `to_json` part is the most important here and the headers have:

```
let(:headers) do
  {
    'Authorization' => 'Basic my-token',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  }
end
```