# How to add as: :json?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, typescript, post

I have this `.ts` file (ruby on rails application), and I have a code like this:

```
export const create = async (params: CreateRequest): Promise<XYZ> => {
  const response = await request<XYZ>(`/api/xyz`, 'post', params);
  return response?.data;
};
```

And I want to make something like this:

```
export const create = async (params: CreateRequest): Promise<XYZ> => {
  const response = await request<XYZ>(`/api/xyz`, 'post', params, as: :json);
  return response?.data;
};
```

And of course, this doesn't work; I'm a noob; please help!

Comment: Hi Alex, are you trying to deliver the payload to the website as JSON? or are you trying to get a response from the website as JSON?

Comment: Hey @Jad. I'm trying to get a response from the website as JSON. 
The problem is that when a query parameter is passed as `nil`, the query is passed to Rails and coerced as an empty string.
It seems that we can prevent this situation like this:
`before { get :index, params: params, as: :json }`
But I'm not able to make it work.
Seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44704018/1407371

Comment: Hey @alex - I believe the example you have linked to is specifically for testing Rails controllers; could you add a snippet of how your Rails routes and controllers are set up?

Answer (score 0):

You can request JSON from a Rails app with the [`Content-Type=Application/JSON` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) (and also [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept)) just like with any other server. See the documentation for whatever `request` is for instructions on how add headers.

In Rails you can also set the format by appending an extension onto to the URL (for example `'/api/xyz.json'`) which overrides the headers.

For a Rails API you can/should also set the default request type with something like `namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do ...` in `config/routes.rb`.